# Regular exp not working in particular cases

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, urllib2

I am unable to extract a particular field while using regex re.search method. 
Error displayed is:

```
raw_add = re.search(search_add.decode('utf-8'),i.decode('utf-8')).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

My code is as follows:

```
import urllib2
import re
from json import dump

dumped_data = []
url = 'http://levi.in/store-finder/content/cityAddress.xml'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

class theAddress():
    city = ""
    state = ""
    lat = ""
    lng = ""
    area = ""
    addr = ""

broken_pieces = re.compile('(?<=marker ).+?(?="\/>)')
all_broken_pieces = re.findall(broken_pieces,data)

search_add = '(?<=html=").+?(?=Tel|<\/p>)'


for i in all_broken_pieces:
    obj = theAddress()
    obj.city = re.search('(?<=city=").+?(?=")',i).group()
    obj.state = re.search('(?<=state=").+?(?=")',i).group()
    obj.lat = re.search('(?<=lat=").+?(?=")',i).group()
    obj.lng = re.search('(?<=lng=").+?(?=")',i).group()
    obj.area = re.search('(?<=label=").+?(?=")',i).group()


    raw_add = re.search(search_add.decode('utf-8'),i.decode('utf-8')).group()
    try:

        process1 = re.sub('&lt;h5&gt;','',raw_add)
        process2 = re.sub('&lt;/h5&gt;',' ',process1)
        process3 = re.sub('&lt;p&gt;','',process2)
        process4 = re.sub('&lt;br /&gt;',' ',process3)
        process5 = re.sub('&lt;/p&gt;','',process4)
        process6 = re.sub('&amp;','&',process5)

        obj.addr = process6
    except:
        pass

    dumped_data.append(obj.__dict__)

    f = open('levis_address1111.json','w')
    dump(dumped_data, f, indent = 1)
```

The problem here is that whenever the regex matched address is ending in 'Tel' the data is extracted but when it ends in '</p>', the error pops.

Comment: Please provide some data example. Your error is caused because you're not checking for `None` while doing `re.search()`. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search): `Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern`. 
If you're trying to extract data from html, you'd be better off using a HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just debugged your piece of code and it seems the strings are html escaped, so you should change your regex to:

```
search_add = '(?<=html=").+?(?=Tel|&lt;\/p&gt;)'
```

Comment: And that's exactly why, normally, you'll want to avoid parsing html with regexes :)

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by beerbajay, if you want to get around the error, check if there is a match at all, before trying to extract the group (which, as the error says, doesn't work on NoneType (no regex match)).

Trying your example and printing some debug info, I find that:

```
debug i: city="Amravati" state="Maharashtra" lat="20.930138" lng="77.754321" html="&lt;h5&gt;Tri Star Retail Pvt. Ltd(OLS):&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;p&gt;Near HDFC Bank,&lt;br /&gt;Main Market Road, &lt;br /&gt;Jaystambh Chowk Road,&lt;br /&gt;Amravati-440601. &lt;br /&gt;Tel: 0721-561396&lt;/p&gt;" label="Amravati" icontype="Levi\'s" category="&lt;h5&gt;Levi\'s Showroom:&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;p&gt;Near HDFC Bank,&lt;br /&gt;Main Market Road, &lt;br /&gt;Jaystambh Chowk Road,&lt;br /&gt;Amravati-440601.&lt;/p&gt;


raw_add: &lt;h5&gt;Tri Star Retail Pvt. Ltd(OLS):&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;p&gt;Near HDFC Bank,&lt;br /&gt;Main Market Road, &lt;br /&gt;Jaystambh Chowk Road,&lt;br /&gt;Amravati-440601. &lt;br /&gt;


debug i: city="Bangalore" state="Karnataka" lat="12.935816" lng="77.610294" html="&lt;img src=\'../Images/FindUs/LoopProgram.gif\' style=\'float:right; padding-left:5px;\' alt=\'Levi\xe2\x80\x99s\xc2\xae Loop Program\' /&gt;&lt;h5&gt;Prakruthi Apparels(OLS):&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;p&gt;Housur road, Forum mall,&lt;br /&gt; Bangalore.&lt;/p&gt;" label="Forum mall" icontype="Levi\'s" category="&lt;img src=\'../Images/FindUs/LoopProgramW.gif\' style=\'float:right; padding-right:5px;\' alt=\'Levi\xe2\x80\x99s\xc2\xae Loop Program\' /&gt;&lt;h5&gt;Levi\'s Showroom:&lt;/h5&gt;&lt;p&gt;Housur road,&lt;br /&gt;Forum mall,&lt;br /&gt; Bangalore.&lt;/p&gt;
```

first 'debug i' is a string that does contain "Tel", so there is a match. In the second one, I don't see any < /p>, so your regex doesn't match. You probably need to do some more debugging of your regex/include some more possible scenario's.
And indeed; usually it's better not to use regexes for html/xml parsing.